# Angle between two lines in term of absolute angles

Tags: geometry

How to find a general equation for an angle between two lines as a function of absolute angles of the two lines? As shown in the figure, i would like to find a general equation to represent angle between the two lines (i.e. $\theta$) in term of absolute angles (i.e. $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$) which are known in this problem.

See figure here

[image: angle between two lines].

What is the general equation for $\theta$ which is valid for all values of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$?

Comment: $\theta + (\phi_{2} - \phi_{1}) = 180^{\circ}$

Comment: TQ. Your answer is straight forward. But how to make sure it generalized for all angles of phi1 and phi2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the angle between two lines is either $|\phi_2 - \phi_1|$ or $180^\circ - |\phi_2-\phi_1|$. Both will work since they add up to $180^\circ$. If you want to know which one is the acute angle (seems to be what you're asking), then it depends on the specific angles

$$ \theta = \begin{cases} \phi_2 - \phi_1 & \text{if}\quad 180^\circ \ge \phi_2 \ge \phi_1 \ge 0^\circ \\
180^\circ - (\phi_2 - \phi_1) & \text{if}\quad 360^\circ \ge \phi_2 \ge 180^\circ \ge \phi_1 \ge 0^\circ \\
\phi_2 - \phi_1 & \textrm{if}\quad 360^\circ \ge \phi_2 \ge \phi_1 \ge 180^\circ 
\end{cases} $$

For your figure, the acute angle is $\theta = 180^\circ - (\phi_2-\phi_1)$

Comment: Tq. I think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you have what you need, make sure to close the question by picking the best answer

Comment: Thank you Dylan. Done.

Answer (score 0):

According to the given  graph $ \theta =180-\phi_2 +  \phi_{1}$.  In general you have to  look at a graph and make a decision.

Comment: This is not true. $\theta \ne \phi_1$. Look at the graph again. One of the lines is not straight.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your comment.