# Geometry : what is the $\phi$ angle, if area of yellow rectangle is equal with area of red triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, rectangles

I have a right triangle and in it area of yellow rectangle is equal with area of red triangle. How could prove that $\phi=45^{\circ}$?

$$\text{Area of  Yellow  Rectangle}=\text{Area  of Red  Triangle}$$

[image]

This problem has no additional information.
I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

**Update:**

If we add some constraint to this problem like bellow, is it have a unique solution?
$$|FG|=x+y$$
[image]

Comment: These are all information you have?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: The yellow ought to be a square, not rectangle. Won't work otherwise

Answer (score 2):

In fact your issue has an infinity of solutions, making angle $\varphi$ dependent on position of point $M$ (see Fig. 1).

Indeed, one can build an infinity of such pairs (rectangle,triangle) with equal area (two examples are given on Fig. 1).

For every  such pair, a specific angle (only exceptionally equal to 45°) is found.

Take a look at the following picture representing the locus of point $M(x,y)$ (common point to the rectangle and the triangle).

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

**Remark :** Let us find the equation of the locus of points $M(x,y)$.

As the area of rectangle with diagonal OM is $xy$ and the area of triangle $MNP$ is $\tfrac12(1-x-y)^2$, we get :

$$(1-x-y)^2=2xy \iff (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1,$$

i.e., is an arc of the circle centered in $(1,1)$ with radius $1$.

[image]

*Fig. 2 : A funny Napoleon's hat : the way $\varphi$ varies (with a maximum of $\pi/4$) when $M$ varies on the arc of circle parametrized by $(x=1-\cos(\phi),y=1-\sin(\phi))$.*

Comment: I think by have an Ellipse we could have B,C and intersection of rectangle and triangle on that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Just aside: I recently see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592698/angle-between-two-lines-in-term-of-absolute-angles) and  in OP, the user  mention the word "absolute angle".  What is absolute angle in geometry? Can you explain sir?

Comment: @Chinnapparaj R In the case of the question you mention, instead of "abolute angles" (which is not standard), I would call these angles "polar angles" because they both refer to a common beginning on the $x$ axis.

Comment: Is there any precise definition of the terms "absolute angles" and "relative angles" are there in geometry? If so, please clarify to me sir!

Comment: so absolute angle means polar angle? right?

Comment: @Chinnapparaj R I advise you to forget "absolute angle" which is ambiguous and keep "polar angle" which is standard, see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarAngle.html . Yes, in the case of this question they mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you sir! still I have one question: relative angle means?

Comment: @Chinnapparaj R "relative angles" is for ordinary angle. In fact, one can draw a parallel with vectors when you write $\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$ : $\vec{AB}$ could be considered as "relative" whereas $\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$ could be said the difference of 2 "absolute" vectors (taking a common origin $O$ is similar to taking a common reference axis $Ox$).

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your thoughts sir! Bye!

Comment: @BarzanHayati I have simplified my text and added a figure. Besides, could you say why did you mentionned an ellipse in your question ?

Comment: I'll present a proposal solution and I think it's not complete and accurate solution

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information the angle $\varphi$ is not always $45^\circ$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be the sides of the rectangle and let $X$ and $Y$ be the legs of the right triangle. Then $xy=XY/2$ and
$$\tan(\varphi)=\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)} \tag{*}$$
where $\tan(\alpha)=(y+Y)/x$ and $\tan(\beta)=y/(x+X)$.

Now let $x=1$, $y=2$, $X=2$ and $Y=2$. Then $xy=XY/2$ but by (*)
$$\tan(\varphi)=10/11\not=1=\tan(45^\circ).$$

On the other hand, as remarked by Quanto, if $x=y$ i.e. the yellow rectangle is a square then by (*)
$$\tan(\varphi)=1=\tan(45^\circ).$$

Comment: I think your answer is partial and needs to be explained more.

Comment: @BarzanHayati See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. [image: Original Question]

first equality: area of red and yellow are equal.
$$ 2xy=vw \label{eq:1} \tag{1}$$

Now by using Thales' theorem in this triangle:

$$ \frac{v+y}{c}=\frac{b-x}{b} \Rightarrow v=c(\frac{b-x}{b})-y       \label{eq:2} \tag{2}$$

$$ \frac{x+w}{b}=\frac{c-y}{c} \Rightarrow w=b(\frac{c-y}{c})-x       \label{eq:3}   \tag{3}$$

by importing $\ref{eq:2}$ and $\ref{eq:3}$ in $\ref{eq:1}$ and simplifying equations, I gained this equation:

$$ \frac{(x-b)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(y-c)^2}{c^2}=1 \label{eq:4}   \tag{4}$$
It's means location of P, which area of red and yellow are equal, is an elliptic with canonical point $B$ and $C$. So we have $\infty$ points for $P$ in the $ABC$.

Now, How to find $\phi$?
[image: Second phase]

By loking at this picture we have:

$$ AG=\sqrt{(x+w)^2+y^2} \label{eq:5}   \tag{5}$$
$$ AF=\sqrt{(y+v)^2+x^2} \label{eq:6}   \tag{6}$$
$$ FG=\sqrt{v^2+w^2} \label{eq:7}   \tag{7}$$

[Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

$$ FG^2=AG^2+AF^2-2AF.FG.\cos(\phi) \label{eq:8}   \tag{8}$$

Now by using $\ref{eq:2}$ and $\ref{eq:3}$ in $\ref{eq:5}$, $\ref{eq:6}$ and $\ref{eq:7}$ and finally in $\ref{eq:8}$, and simplifying that, I reach to this equation:

$$ \sqrt{\left[\frac{b^2}{c^2}(c-y)^2+y^2 \right]\left[\frac{c^2}{b^2}(b-x)^2+x^2 \right]}\cos(\phi)= \left[bx+cy-xy(\frac{b^2+c^2}{bc})\right]\label{eq:9}   \tag{9}$$

So

$$ \cos(\phi)=\frac{\left[bx+cy-xy(\frac{b^2+c^2}{bc})\right]}{\sqrt{\left[\frac{b^2}{c^2}(c-y)^2+y^2 \right]\left[\frac{c^2}{b^2}(b-x)^2+x^2 \right]}}\label{eq:10}   \tag{10}$$

$$for \: b > x > 0 \: and \: c > y > 0 \: $$
For finding a $\phi$ as a function on $x$ and $y$ we need to considering $\ref{eq:4}$ and $\ref{eq:9}$. If I find exact solution I post it here.

I have writed a python code for determine all possible solution of this equation, but this not have a unique solution. Since all $x$ and $y$ that for them we have $\cos(\phi)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ are solutions.